# How can I suppress warnings in generated code?

Tags: haskell, ghc, compiler-warnings, generated-code

I'm building a lexer and parser with Alex and Happy. The code they generate throws a huge number of warnings with `ghc-options: -Wall` turned on in my project's .cabal file.

This makes it difficult to catch real warnings. How can I turn off the warnings only inside the generated files? I know it can be done with a pragma:

```
{#- GHC_OPTIONS -w -#}
```

But I can't think of an easy way to stick this pragma at the top of every generated file, every time they're rebuilt.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: How about organizing your cabal file so that the alex and happy modules are in their own library component, and use `ghc-options: -w` for that component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical alex file begins with some stuff at the top - usually a module declaration which will get copied verbatim into the generated file:

```
{
module Main where
}
%wrapper "basic"
...
```

So just add the GHC_OPTIONS pragma before the `module Main ...` line, e.g.:

```
{
{-# GHC_OPTIONS -w #-}
module Main where
}
%wrapper "basic"
```

and it will be present in your generated file. The same can be done with happy files.